# How should I recover.m file of the function in the toolbox?

Tags: matlab

Mistakenly modified the .m file that came with MATLAB. How should I recover it?

Why doesn't MATLAB make the .m file of the function in the toolbox "read-only" Does anyone know why?Is there any way to change all MATLAB official .m files to "read-only"?

How should I recover it?

Comment: could you specify which .m file and share the code of how you modified it?

Comment: Reinstall MATLAB?

Comment: If you don't want to reinstall Matlab and have access to [Matlab Online](https://matlab.mathworks.com/), you can open the file there to see its original source code

Comment: @Wolfie Thanks for your advice. but it's too time consuming

Comment: @Luis Mendo，Thanks for your comment, It's sounds good.But I can not find original source code on https://matlab.mathworks.com/

Comment: Reinstalling is the only way. I think the installation will be relatively quick if you install over an existing installation.

Comment: "it's too time consuming", but also would have taken significantly less time than the 6hrs between your question and your comment...

Comment: @Wolfie  Yes. In fact, I restored the file after making the changes. But I want to find a way to quickly recover from the worst-case scenario in the future.

Comment: *But I want to find a way to quickly recover from the worst-case scenario in the future.* I believe this is called 'a backup'.